# Error testing and control from DOS

Tags: error-handling, batch-file, sqlcmd

I'm running DOS 6.0.6002 on a windows server enterprise system, SP2.
SQL Server 2008 R2  (10.50.4000)
I have a main control program in DOS.
I'm invoking an sql program through sqlcmd.
A simplified version looks like this:

```
set sqlsvr=myServer
set logfile=logfile.txt
sqlcmd -S %sqlsvr%  -d myDB -i import_some_stuff.sql > "%logfile%" 2>&1
echo error level = %ERRORLEVEL%
```

I need this program to be pretty robust.  It has to run every day against a lot of files and tables.  If it fails, I need to catch it and notify sysadmin.  For now, just catch it.

So to test this, I've tried the following tests:

1) Renaming the file to one that does not exist.
  Result: it returns and errorlevel of 1 (that is it caught the error!) bravo!

2) typing in some syntactical rubbish at the front of the sql program.
  Result: it prints the error message in the log file, BUT it DOES NOT return an error (so the return value in %ERRORLEVEL% is zero.  This seems incredible to me.  What am I missing?

Comment: Robust and _Batch scripting_ don't go very well together...  Why not something like powershell or perl or ...?

Comment: cmd.exe is a windows console-mode program that has nothing whatsoever to do with DOS. The resemblance is purely superficial.

Comment: I didn't realize that, Bill. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `-b` option to sqlcmd:

> **-b**
>
> Specifies that sqlcmd exits and returns a DOS ERRORLEVEL value when an 
>   error occurs. 
>   The value that is returned to the DOS ERRORLEVEL
>   variable is 1 when the SQL Server error message has a severity level
>   greater than 10; otherwise, the value returned is 0. If the -V option
>   has been set in addition to -b, sqlcmd will not report an error if the
>   severity level is lower than the values set using -V. Command prompt
>   batch files can test the value of ERRORLEVEL and handle the error
>   appropriately. sqlcmd does not report errors for severity level 10
>   (informational messages).
>
> If the sqlcmd script contains an incorrect comment, syntax error, 
>   or is missing a scripting variable, ERRORLEVEL returned is 1.

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

Comment: @elbillaf If it resolves your question, you might want to mark this as the answer.